# Negative flux values in radio maps?

Tags: radio-astronomy

I am trying to understand some maps of radio emission in e.g the Milky Way. I continue to see in papers that these radio maps report negative values of the flux in Jansky units, although no explanation is given as to why.

For example Figure 1 here: [The 1.28 GHz MeerKAT Galactic Center Mosaic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10541.pdf) and here: [Towards a More Complex Understanding of Natal Super Star Clusters with Multiwavelength Observations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02695.pdf)

[image]
I am wondering if the negative values are simply due to background subtraction, or if there is something more complicated going on.

If it's just background subtraction, a simple reference explainaing how the background subtraction is done in general would be useful.